# i want to use 2 android themes in android manifist?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-manifest, android-theme

i try to use 2 themes in one activity,one for dialog and one for hiding the title bar, in the AndroidManifest:

```
<activity>
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
    android:label="@string/app_name" > (it show X here!!)
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

i can only use one at a time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

in your `Activity` to remove the `ActionbBar`. You should use it before `setContentView`.

If you use `requestWindowFeature` remove the `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this. In Styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<style name="ExampleTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
      <!-- <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/new_indicator</item> -->
     <!--  <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/new_indicator</item> -->
</style>

 <style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/new_indicator</item>
       <!-- <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/new_indicator</item>  -->
</style>
```

In your menifeast.xml

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/ExampleTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.ebizzinfotech.regularcoupon.SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 <activity android:name="com.ebizzinfotech.regularcoupon.MainActivity"  
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
</activity>
```